# Deserialize avro message without schema

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry, confluent-kafka-python

I have to decode avro messages without any schema as there are some fields where logical type is defined as date and there are values in the filed which are garbage value and because of that all the records are rejecting, Is there a way to consume those records.

I am using confluent kafka consumer api.

Answer (score 0):

Avro requires both a reader and writer schema for deserialization. If you don't have either, then you will be unable to consume the data.